# $T$-invariant space of dimension $m$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace

I have the following problem:

> Let $K$ be a field and let $V$ be a finite dimension $K$-vector space. Let $T \colon V \longrightarrow V$ be a linear transformation with minimal polynomial of degree $m$. Show that $V$ has a $T$-invariant subspace of dimension $m$.

I wanted to use that $V$ is isomorphic to $K[t]$-cyclic modules of the form
$$V \cong \frac{K[t]}{\langle f_1\rangle} \oplus \frac{K[t]}{\langle f_2\rangle} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{K[t]}{\langle m_T\rangle}$$
where $f_i$ divides $f_{i + 1}$, $f_i$ is the minimal polynomial of the corresponding restriction of $T$ and $m_T$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$. But I got stuck.

Is my way correct? Or am I getting more complicated than neccesary? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: $K[t]/\langle m_T\rangle$ looks like an $m$-dimensional space.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier so I need to show that it is $T$-invariant, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. $K[t]/\langle m_T\rangle$ is isomorphic to a cyclic subspace, and a cyclic subspace is $T$-invariant.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Thank you so much!